# list-style-type shows 'invalid property value' in Chrome

Tags: html, cross-browser

The code can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3Q06VJHA1CZ

In Firefox, `list-style-type: "[+]"` works as desired, replacing the arrow with the plus symbol. However, when run in Chrome, it defaults to the arrow, and the Inspect Element shows that the assignment has 'Invalid Property Value'.

How to make the behavior same for the two browsers?

Also, is there any way to add space between the `[+]` and `me`? I tried padding and margin, but it wasn't working.